# What is wrong with this javascript date conversion in a jade template?

Tags: javascript, pug

I am using this in my jade template:

```
span.date
        - function convertDate(dateString) {var date = new Date(dateString);return date.getDate()+"."+date.getMonth()+"."+date.getFullYear();}
        | #{convertDate(tile.date)}
```

while iterating over tiles.

For the input "2016-07-14" the return is "14.6.2016", for "2016-08-09" -> "9.7.2016" etc.

Why does a month get lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date.getMonth()` returns the month index, which is 0-based.

To convert it to month position you need to add `1` to its value.